# opening a popup in IE - "Member not found"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf, popup

This happens in IE6 when the user opens a popup window that opens a PDF inside. (this part works).

Then, the user opens another popup window, and at this point i get this error.

There is a [good description and a possible solution here](http://www.techcrony.info/?p=24)

my question is this:

Is there a better solution? Opening up a window and closing it right away seems like a silly solution to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've got a better solution that doesn't involve closing the window first. The issue is that IE won't override a window (PDF or otherwise) if you attempt to open it again with an empty URL (i.e., ''). It *will* override a PDF with a non-empty URL, however. That could be a file, but about:blank works even better (which is what an empty URL does normally).

Depending on how your code is written, you may still want the try/catch, but this should eliminate the need:

```
windowHandle = window.open('about:blank',name,attributes);
windowHandle.document.location.href = url;
windowHandle.focus();
```

about:blank will force the PDF out of the child window and allow you to do what you need to do. It might not be a bad idea to place the setting of the URL and focus() in a windowHandle.onload() handler, so there aren't any timing issues with disposing of the PDF. I.e.:

```
windowHandle.onload=function(){
    windowHandle.document.location.href = url;
    windowHandle.focus();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem using a try catch block.

```
windowHandle = window.open('',name,attributes);
try {
    windowHandle.document.location.href = url;
} catch (exc) {
    windowHandle.close();
    windowHandle = window.open('',name,attributes);
    windowHandle.document.location.href = url + suffix;
}
windowHandle.focus();
```

Seems to work for me.

Comment: Interesting, next time this comes up ill try your solution